# Errors with Locust load testing scripts - Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

I am new to Locust Load testing framework and in process of  migrating my existing Azure cloud based Performance testing C# scripts to Locust's Python based scripts. Our team almost completed migration of scripts. But during our load tests, we are getting errors as below, which fails to create new requests from the machine due to high CPU utilization or because of so many exception on Locust. We are running with Locust web based mode - details are indicated below. These scritps are working fine on smaller loads of 50 to 100 users

"**Error 1 -('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)**)"

"**Error 2 : Connection pool is full, discarding connection**"

"** **Error 3 :urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out****"

Yes, we are using UrlLibs on the utility classes . But first 2 error does seems to be of Locust.

Our Load testing configurations  are : "**3500 users at a hatch rate of 5 users per second**". Running natively(no docker container) on a 8 Core , 16 Gb Linux Ubuntu Virtual machine on Azure. ulimit set as 50,000 on Linux machine.

Please help us with your thoughts

**Sample test is as below**

```
import os 
import sys
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('WORKDIR', os.getcwd()))

from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
from locust.wait_time import between

class ContactUsBehavior(TaskSet):


    wait_time = AppUtil.get_wait_time_function(2)


    @task(1)
    def post_load_test_contact(self):
        data = { "ContactName" : "Mane"
            , "Email" : "someone@someone.com"
            , "EmailVerifaction" : "someone@someone.com"
            , "TelephoneContact" : ""
            , "PhoneNumber" : ""
            , "ContactReason" : "Other"            
            , "OtherComment" : "TEST Comments 2019-12-30"
            , "Agree" : "true"
             }
        self.client.post("app/contactform", self.client, 'Contact us submission', post_data = data)


class UnauthenticatedUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = ContactUsBehavior
    # host is override-able
    host = 'https://app.devurl.com/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Locust’s default HTTP client uses python-requests which internally use urllib3 . 
If you are working on a large scale tests, you should consider another HTTP client. The connection pool of urllib 3 (PoolManager ) will reuse connections and limit how many connections are allowed per host at any given time to avoid accumulating too many unused sockets. 
So you have option to tweak the pool : https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#customizing-pool-behavior

Or you can try  any other high performance HTTP client . Eg: [gevenhttp](https://github.com/gwik/geventhttpclient/)
Locust also provides a built-int client which is faster than the default python-requests:
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html

You should consider to run Locust in cluster mode in different nodes if the client still couldn't handle the big load.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try this soon and let you know.

Comment: we checked both FastHttpLocust and gevenhttp clients, but both dont have an attributes on the response object that helps with URL of the response. Means we are checking Url of http response on the default locust http client to compare where the user lands after certain actions. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: We solved this issue by adding more slaves on the same machine, since python will use only 1 core at a time. so we opened new locust slaves on the same amchine so that it uses other "un-used" cores to create more requests/connections